# Socket.io server Giving me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

Hey Guys I'm getting a connection refused error when running a server. I am trying to build a simple chat application using react.

On the back end I have

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();


server = app.listen(5000, function(){
    console.log('server is running on port 5000')
});

io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', function(data){
        io.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', data);
    })
});
```

On the front end app.js I have :

```
import React from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

class Chat extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            message: '',
            messages: []
        };

        this.socket = io('localhost:5000');

        this.socket.on('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', function(data){
            addMessage(data);
        });

        const addMessage = data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({messages: [...this.state.messages, data]});
            console.log(this.state.messages);
        };

        this.sendMessage = ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            this.socket.emit('SEND_MESSAGE', {
                author: this.state.username,
                message: this.state.message
            })
            this.setState({message: ''});

        }
    }
```

I have made sure my file structure is set up correctly. I have it listening on port 5000, but I have also tried listening on port 3000, since thats what my npm start takes me to to run my Chat App. Same error. If I change it to port 3000 I sometimes get a 404 not found error as well if that's helpful. I don't have a lot of experience with react OR socket.io but this has been hurting my head. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is all your code, and if you start your server with `npm start` as you mention it, here is what happens:

- by default (check your `package.json` file), `npm start` starts a [default server](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-start) that just serves your files in `src`. It's very useful to develop your frontend but it **does not run your server code**. So the running server does not listen to websocket. So you get the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.
- if you configured `npm start` to run your server code, it will listen to websocket but it will **not serve your HTML files**. Because you just forgot that part in your code. So you'll get 404.

I suggest you build your bundle and serve it. To do so, add this line in your `server.js` before `app.listen()`:

```
app.use(express.static('./build'));
```

And you run your server like this:

```
npm run build
node server.js
```

You can also prefer to run the app in development mode but I would need to search for the commands and give them to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation it helped me understand a little better. However, I attempted to run the server using your commands and added the line of code you gave me but I'm still getting the same error. I do have more code than this, but most of it is for other pages in the app build. Should I be going back to the main root folder to run the node server? or should I stay in my client folder and run the app. For testing purposes I tried both and still receiving the same error. I can link the github repo if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, of course, you have to check the path to your `build` directory. It could be something like `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));`. Check this page for more setup info: https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/getting-started-with-your-react-app-with-express-server-1c701a3c6edb